# What are 'weapon proficiencies'?

Tags: ascendant

The *Spirit of the Master* spirit says something about boosting 'weapon proficiencies'.  What are these proficiencies, exactly?  Presumably it's related to one of the weapons stats or abilities, but I'm not sure which ones.

[image: Weapon Proficiencies]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weapon proficiencies increase the effect of the blue text on weapons. The weapon proficiency of each character is their starting weapon. For example, Theseus starts with a notched weapon, so any notched weapon will deal more bleeding damage when wielded by Theseus.

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/296930/discussions/0/540741859344259313/)

Straight from the <strike>horse's</strike> dev's mouth:

> Basically, weapons are setup into tiers and you will receive the
>   higher tier proficiency bonus when you pick up a weapon that you are
>   proficient with.
>
> For example, Theseus can pick up a Razor and only receive a +2% bonus
>   chance to proc a Blessing. Memnon and Hanuman can pick up the same
>   Razor and they will receive the bonus of the next tier i.e. a 4%
>   chance to proc a Blessing.
>
> Here are the weapon proficiencies. The bolded value is a tier bonus
>   only attainable by characters that are proficient with that weapon.
>
> ```
> Razor = +2% / +4% / +6% chance to proc Blessing
> Axe = 3% / 6% / 9% chance to crit
> Mace = 10% / 20% / 30% spell cost reduction
> Notched = +10 / +20 / +30 bleeding damage
> Curved = 5% / 10% / 15% chance to autoparry 
> Hand = 20% / 40% / 60% chance enemies drop influence
> Gada = +5 / +10 / +15 magnet range
> ```

Furthermore, that particular spirit causes an increase of half again the normal tier increase. For example, if you had mace proficiency and the Spirit of the Master, your tiers would look like:

```
Mace = 15% / 25% / 35% spell cost reduction
```

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/296930/discussions/0/522729359396289888/)

Comment: So does 'boosting' it only work if you have the right character/weapon combo?

Comment: That's what it sounds like.